# FFMPEG: While decoding video, is possible to generate result to user's provided buffer?

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, directx

In ffmpeg decoding video scenario, **H264** for example, typically we allocate an `AVFrame` and decode the compressed data, then we get the result from the member `data` and `linesize` of `AVFrame`. As following code:

```
// input setting: data and size are a H264 data.
AVPacket avpkt;
av_init_packet(&avpkt);
avpkt.data = const_cast<uint8_t*>(data);
avpkt.size = size;

// decode video: H264 ---> YUV420
AVFrame *picture = avcodec_alloc_frame();
int len = avcodec_decode_video2(context, picture, &got_picture, &avpkt);
```

We may use the result to do something other tasks, for example, using DirectX9 to render. That is, to prepare buffers(DirectX9 Textures), and copy from the result of decoding.

```
D3DLOCKED_RECT lrY;
D3DLOCKED_RECT lrU;
D3DLOCKED_RECT lrV;
textureY->LockRect(0, &lrY, NULL, 0);
textureU->LockRect(0, &lrU, NULL, 0);
textureV->LockRect(0, &lrV, NULL, 0);

// copy YUV420: picture->data ---> lr.pBits.
my_copy_image_function(picture->data[0], picture->linesize[0], lrY.pBits, lrY.Pitch, width, height);
my_copy_image_function(picture->data[1], picture->linesize[1], lrU.pBits, lrU.Pitch, width / 2, height / 2);
my_copy_image_function(picture->data[2], picture->linesize[2], lrV.pBits, lrV.Pitch, width / 2, height / 2);
```

This process is considered that **2 copy** happens(ffmpeg copy result to picture->data, and then copy picture->data to DirectX9 Texture).

My question is: is it possible to improve the process to only **1 copy** ? On the other hand, can we provide buffers(`pBits`, the buffer of DirectX9 textures) to ffmpeg, and decode function results to buffer of DirectX9 texture, not to buffers of `AVFrame` ?

Comment: I retagged your question from OpenGL -> DirectX. At least for me there is no indicator that the question is related to OpenGL, but if I missed something feel free to revert it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the way out.

There is a public member of `AVCodecContext`, **get_buffer2**, which is a callback function. While calling `avcodec_decode_video2`, this callback function will be invoked, and this callback function is responsible to delegate buffers and some informations to `AVFrame`, then `avcodec_decode_video2` generate the result to the buffers of `AVFrame`.

The callback function, **get_buffer2**, is set `avcodec_default_get_buffer2` as default. However, we can override this as our privided function. For example:

```
void our_buffer_default_free(void *opaque, uint8_t *data)
{
    // empty
}
int our_get_buffer(struct AVCodecContext *c, AVFrame *pic, int flags)
{
    assert(c->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
    pic->data[0] = lrY.pBits;
    pic->data[1] = lrU.pBits;
    pic->data[2] = lrV.pBits;
    picture->linesize[0] = lrY.Pitch;
    picture->linesize[1] = lrU.Pitch;
    picture->linesize[2] = lrV.Pitch;
    pic->buf[0] = av_buffer_create(pic->data[0], pic->linesize[0] * pic->height, our_buffer_default_free, NULL, 0);
    pic->buf[1] = av_buffer_create(pic->data[1], pic->linesize[1] * pic->height / 2, our_buffer_default_free, NULL, 0);
    pic->buf[2] = av_buffer_create(pic->data[2], pic->linesize[2] * pic->height / 2, our_buffer_default_free, NULL, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Before decoding, we override the callback function:

```
context->get_buffer2 = our_get_buffer;
```

Then `avcodec_decode_video2` will generate the result to our provided buffers.

By the way, for C++ programs which often implementing these processes in classes, we can record this pointer first:

```
context->opaque = this;
```

And define the overridden callback function as static member:

```
static int myclass::my_get_buffer(struct AVCodecContext *c, AVFrame *pic, int flags)
{
    auto this_pointer = static_cast<decode_context*>(c->opaque);
    return this_pointer->my_get_buffer_real(c, pic, flags);
}
int myclass::my_get_buffer_real(struct AVCodecContext *c, AVFrame *pic, int flags)
{
    // ditto with above our_get_buffer.
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Note that performance will suffer if you don't meet the alignment expectations of the CODEC.  If it's compatible with your output device, I would ensure at least 128b alignment of the buffer and each row (via strides).  If that is *not* compatible with your output it may be faster to do the copy as you originally had it.