# How do I pre-allocate the memory for libavcodec to write decoded frame data?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav

I am trying to decode a video with libav by following the demo code: [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/decode_video.c)

I need to be able to control where the frame data in `pFrame->data[0]` is stored. I  have tried setting `pFrame->data` to my own buffer as follows:

```
// Determine required buffer size and allocate buffer 
int numBytes = av_image_get_buffer_size(pixFmt, width, height, 1); 
(uint8_t*) dataBuff = (uint8_t*) malloc (numBytes * sizeof(uint8_t)); 

// Assign buffer to image planes in pFrame
av_image_fill_arrays(frame->data, frame->linesize, dataBuff, pixFmt, width,
height, 1);
```

While this does set `pFrame->data` to be `dataBuff` (if I print their addresses, they are the same), this call `ret = avcodec_receive_frame(pCodecContext, pFrame)` to receive the decoded data always writes the data to a different address. It seems to manage its own memory somewhere in the underlying API and ignores the `dataBuff` that I assigned to `pFrame` right before.

So I'm stuck--how can I tell `libav` to write decoded frame data to memory that I pre-allocate? I've seen people ask  similar questions online and in the libav forum but haven't been able to find an answer.

Many thanks~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the proper way to do it is via the callback function `get_buffer2` to create your own custom allocator as this answer demonstrates:

[FFMPEG: While decoding video, is possible to generate result to user's provided buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339980/ffmpeg-while-decoding-video-is-possible-to-generate-result-to-users-provided?rq=1)

Further documentation is [here](https://libav.org/documentation/doxygen/master/structAVCodecContext.html#a7c93198032a3a728b13cb7d7e637d295)!