# How to use FFMPEG API to decode to client allocated memory

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec, libavformat

I'm trying to use the FFMPEG API to decode into a buffer defined by the client program by following the tips in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339980/ffmpeg-while-decoding-video-is-possible-to-generate-result-to-users-provided?rq=1) but using the new pattern for decoding instead of the now deprecated `avcodec_decode_video2` function.

If my input file is an I-frame only format, everything works great. I've tested with a .mov file encoded with v210 (uncompressed).

However, if the input is a long-GoP format (I'm trying with H.264 high profile 4:2:2 in an mp4 file) I get the following pleasingly psychedelic/impressionistic result:

[image: Crowd run. On acid!]

There's clearly something *motion-vectory* going on here!

And if I let FFMPEG manage its own buffers with the H.264 input by *not* overriding  `AVCodecContext::get_buffer2`, I can make a copy from the resulting frame to my desired destination buffer and get good results.

Here's my decoder method, `_frame` and `_codecCtx` are object members of type `AVFrame*` and `AVCodecContext*` respectively. They get alloc'd and init'd in the constructor.

```
        virtual const DecodeResult decode(const rv::sz_t toggle) override {
        _toggle = toggle & 1;
        using Flags_e = DecodeResultFlags_e;
        DecodeResult ans(Flags_e::kNoResult);

        AVPacket pkt;   // holds compressed data
        ::av_init_packet(&pkt);
        pkt.data = NULL;
        pkt.size = 0;
        int ret;

        // read the compressed frame to decode
        _err = av_read_frame(_fmtCtx, &pkt);
        if (_err < 0) {
            if (_err == AVERROR_EOF) {
                ans.set(Flags_e::kEndOfFile);
                _err = 0; // we can safely ignore EOF errors
                return ans;
            } else {
                baleOnFail(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
            }
        } 

        // send (compressed) packets to the decoder until it produces an uncompressed frame
        do {

            // sender
            _err = ::avcodec_send_packet(_codecCtx, &pkt);
            if (_err < 0) {
                if (_err == AVERROR_EOF) {
                    _err = 0; // EOFs are ok
                    ans.set(Flags_e::kEndOfFile);
                    break;
                } else {
                    baleOnFail(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
                }
            }

            // receiver
            ret = ::avcodec_receive_frame (_codecCtx, _frame);
            if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN)) {
                continue;
            } else if (ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
                ans.set(Flags_e::kEndOfFile);
                break;
            } else if (ret < 0) {
                _err = ret;
                baleOnFail(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
            } else {
                ans.set(Flags_e::kGotFrame);
            }

            av_packet_unref (&pkt);

        } while (!ans.test(Flags_e::kGotFrame));        

        //packFrame(); <-- used to copy to client image

        return ans;
    }
```

And here's my override for `get_buffer2`

```
        int getVideoBuffer(struct AVCodecContext* ctx, AVFrame* frm) {
        // ensure frame pointers are all null
        if (frm->data[0] || frm->data[1] || frm->data[2] || frm->data[3]){
            ::strncpy (_errMsg, "non-null frame data pointer detected.", AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE);
            return -1;
        }

        // get format descriptor, ensure it's valid.
        const AVPixFmtDescriptor *desc = av_pix_fmt_desc_get(static_cast<AVPixelFormat>(frm->format));
        if (!desc) {
            ::strncpy (_errMsg, "Pixel format descriptor not available.", AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE);
            return AVERROR(EINVAL);
        }

        // for Video, extended data must point to the same place as data.
        frm->extended_data = frm->data;

        // set the data pointers to point at the Image data.
        int chan = 0;
        IMG* img = _imgs[_toggle];
        // initialize active channels
        for (; chan < 3; ++chan) {
            frm->buf[chan] =  av_buffer_create (
                static_cast<uint8_t*>(img->begin(chan)),
                rv::unsigned_cast<int>(img->size(chan)),
                Player::freeBufferCallback, // callback does nothing
                reinterpret_cast<void*>(this),
                0 // i.e. AV_BUFFER_FLAG_READONLY is not set
            );
            frm->linesize[chan] = rv::unsigned_cast<int>(img->stride(chan));
            frm->data[chan] = frm->buf[chan]->data;
        }
        // zero out inactive channels
        for (; chan < AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS; ++chan) {
            frm->data[chan] = NULL;
            frm->linesize[chan] = 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I can reason that the codec needs to keep reference frames in memory and so I'm not really surprised that this isn't working, but I've not been able to figure out how to have it deliver clean decoded frames to client memory. I thought that `AVFrame::key_frame` would have been a clue, but, after observing its behaviour in gdb, it doesn't provide a useful trigger for when to allocate `AVFrame::buf`s from the buffer pool and when they can be initialized to point at client memory.

Grateful for any help!

Comment: 2 questions: 1) "I can make a copy from the resulting frame to my desired destination buffer and get good results.". Why don't you? 2) Perhaps B-Frames causes the problem. Can you try a video source w/o B-Frames?

Comment: Thanks @thekamilz, 1) that’s my workaround, but it’d be quicker if I could avoid the extra copy step. 2) I already did this as described in the post and sure enough, it worked just fine.

Comment: If I understand correctly, All you need is reorder the frames according to PTS before delivering to client. My suggestions; perhaps using a priority queue (based on PTS) to keep frames as a re-order buffer then deliver it to the client (in PTS order).